# How to handle & and other special character in SimpleXML PHP

Tags: php

I have used SimpleXMLElement for creating xml But it cannot handle &. Here is my code

```
$contacts = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Contacts></Contacts>');
$name = $contacts->addChild('name', 'You & Me');
$name->addAttribute('no', '1');
echo $contacts->asXML();
```

And here is the output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Contacts><name no="1">You </name></Contacts>
```

How to solve this Question. I want a solution for all special character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you without using html codes, because this way it automatically escapes it:

(Because `addChild()` only escapes `<` and `>`, but not `&`)

```
$contacts = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Contacts></Contacts>');
$contacts->name[0] = 'You & Me';
$contacts->name[0]->addAttribute('no', '1');
echo $contacts->asXML();
```

Output (Source code):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Contacts><name no="1">You &amp; Me</name></Contacts>
```

Comment: If I have more then one child with same name then what to do ??

Comment: @Md.Yusuf Then make sure to specify it like this: `$contacts->name[2] = 'You & Me';` And if you don't know the number and just want to append one do: `$contacts->name[] = 'You & Me';`

Comment: @Md.Yusuf BTW: If you want a full explanation why this is handled like this see this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/552957/3933332

Answer (score 3):

You have to replace it with e.g html code http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm or check this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

```
$contacts = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Contacts></Contacts>');
$name = $contacts->addChild('name', 'You &amp; Me');
$name->addAttribute('no', '1');
echo $contacts->asXML();
```

you can use also a function htmlspecialchars to do it

```
$contacts = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Contacts></Contacts>');
$name = $contacts->addChild('name', htmlspecialchars('You & Me', ENT_QUOTES, "utf-8"));
$name->addAttribute('no', '1');
echo $contacts->asXML();
```