# DOMDocument::createElement(): unterminated entity reference （PHP)

Tags: php

I tried this code in PHP;

```
$oItem->appendChild($oDom->createElement("link", $iItem->item($i)->getElementsByTagName("affiliateUrl")->item(0)->nodeValue));
```

But it shows error

> DOMDocument::createElement(): unterminated entity reference

Is this because of getElementsByTagName contain `< >` ?

Please advise how to fix it?

That tag is:

```
<affiliateUrl>http://hb.afl.rakuten.co.jp/hgc/sd0ps992.2asad607.g00ps016.2asfefe9/?pc=http%3A%2F%2Fitem.rakuten.co.jp%2Fmarukans%2Fno11-1%2F&m=http%3A%2F%2Fm.rakuten.co.jp%2Fmarukans%2Fi%2F10000152%2F</affiliateUrl>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What does `$iItem->item($i)->getElementsByTagName("affiliateUrl")->item(0)->nodeValue` contain?

Comment: It contains URL link.

Comment: With a GET parameter in it, `&`? You can probably use `htmlspecialchars` but without knowing the actual string its hard to help.

Comment: Thanks. Please see the full code here  (http://kumiko-jp.com/archives/32522.html)  I guess because getElementsByTagName is trying to get URL link of TAG <affiliateUrl> but it can not get for some reasons.....

Comment: What is the full tag/content? I think the answer to your question is to use that function on that value. For a detailed explanation on this see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/552957/rationale-behind-simplexmlelements-handling-of-text-values-in-addchild-and-adda. An `&` in XML without an `;` is invalid.

Comment: Thanks. the full tag contains  <affiliateUrl>http://hb.afl.rakuten.co.jp/hgc/g00ps992.2asad607.g00ps016.2asfefe9/?pc=http%3A%2F%2Fitem.rakuten.co.jp%2Fmarukans%2Fno11-1%2F&m=http%3A%2F%2Fm.rakuten.co.jp%2Fmarukans%2Fi%2F10000152%2F</affiliateUrl>

Comment: You need to add the code/tag to the question as a code block.

Comment: I can not get the affiliateUrl by using getElementsByTagName("affiliateUrl")

Comment: Thanks. I added <affiliURL> to the question

Comment: You tried the `htmlspecialchars` and it failed? Your `F&m` should break the current XML parser.. It needs to be `F&amp;m` or some entity variation of that.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the issue :
Use the **htmlentitites** function to convert all applicable characters to HTML entities, **htmlentitites** = Convert all applicable characters to HTML entities.
For example:

```
$dom->createElement(‘value’, htmlentities($text_value));
```